# Store PHP and HTML output within variable

Tags: php, html

I have the following code:

```
echo "Hi " . $firstName . ",  <br /><br /> text <br /> <br />";
$i = 0;
foreach ($urls as $key) {
print_r ('<a href="' . ($key) . '">');
print_r($names[$i] . "</a>");
echo "<br /> <br />";
$i++;
}
echo "text, <br /><br /> text";
```

This prints out a message with a list of links generated by the foreach loop. I'd like to store the result in a variable (which I use as the body of an email).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do as

```
$body = '';
foreach ($urls as $key) {
$body .= '<a href="' . ($key) . '">';
$body .= $names[$i] . "</a>";
$body .= "<br /> <br />";
$i++;
}
```

Here initializing a var $body and inside the loop concatenating the result into body so that you can use it later.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Here added `$data` variable and `$data .=` concatenated the results in variable.

```
    $data = "Hi " . $firstName . ",  <br /><br /> text <br /> <br />";
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($urls as $key) {
        $data .='<a href="' . ($key) . '">'.$names[$i] . "</a><br /> <br />";
        $i++;
    }
    $data .="text, <br /><br /> text";      
    echo $data;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just concat the new strings with a summation of the previous strings.

```
$output = "Hi $firstName,<br/><br/>text<br/><br/>";
$i = 0;
foreach ($urls as $key) {
    $output .= '<a href="' . $key . '">' . $names[$i] . "</a><br/><br/>";
    $i++;
}
$output .= "text,<br/><br/>text";
echo $output;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `ob_*` functions.  Specifically `ob_start`, `ob_get_contents`, and `ob_end_clean`

In your case, it would be:

```
ob_start();

echo "Hi " . $firstName . ",  <br /><br /> text <br /> <br />";
$i = 0;
foreach ($urls as $key) {
    print_r ('<a href="' . ($key) . '">');
    print_r($names[$i] . "</a>");
    echo "<br /> <br />";
    $i++;
}
echo "text, <br /><br /> text";

$body = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```